# Share Linux Ethernet Connection to Windows laptop over WiFi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to get my Windows 8 laptop to use my Linux's internet connection. I'm pretty far from my router (other side of the house) and since my Linux computer uses a lan cable, it doesn't experiance any of the connection issues my laptop does from the distance.

I have a wifi card in my Linux PC, and I've setup an ad-hoc network on it, I can get the Windows laptop to connect to the ad-hoc network, however, I am unable to get it internet access.

My Linux PC's Ethernet connection info:
IPv4
IP Address: 192.168.1.152
Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Route: 192.168.1.1
Primary DNS: 192.168.1.1

The Linux wifi ad-hoc connection info:
IPv4
IP Address: 10.42.0.1
Broadcast Address: 10.42.0.255
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

The windows network details when connected to the ad-hoc:
IP Address: 192.168.1.153
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Primary DNS: 8.8.8.8

However, when I ping 192.186.1.1 from the windows machine, I get:
pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.153: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.153: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.153: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.153: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
  Packets: Sent: 4, Recieved: 4, Lost: 0 (0% loss),

I suspect this is due to the ad-hoc info on the Linux machine being 10.42.1 instead of 192.168.1  but I am unsure how to correct this, or if this is the real problem.

I'm not a 100% linux noob, but I have very little experience with networking.
Any help would be great.

If it helps narrow down the solution; I'm running on Fedora 22 with the MATE desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Linux machine is acting as a gateway. In order for the Windows machine to communicate on the other side of the Linux machine, it first has to know the IP address of the Linux machine. It also can only communicate if it is in the same subnet.

**Therfore...**

The windows machine needs to be somewhere in between 10.42.0.2 and 10.42.0.254 with its gateway set to the IP of the linux machine.

Comment: On Windows machine:
IP Address: 10.42.0.2
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 10.42.0.1

Didn't work, same problem.
Network connection state says "No Network access"

Comment: did you try pinging 10.42.0.1 from your windows machine?

Comment: ping 10.42.0.1
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: What happens you set your IP setting to DHCP?

Comment: it doesn't give the windows any ip or gateway information at all

Comment: how did you set up the ad-hoc network?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35010/discussion-between-badge-be-and-josh-raymond).

Comment: through the GUI on the desktop - left clicked on network icon - create wireless network - gave it a name and a WEP key for security, it defaulted to ad-hoc and the iopv4 is set to "shared to other computers"

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you connect to linux machine .. your windows  should be getting the ip between 10.42.0.2 and 10.42.0.254 so that they can be in same networks then only you can have connection with the linux add hoc.
Now what you can do is after connecting to add hoc in your windows machine's **command prompt** type

**>ip release** and enter

**>ip renew** and enter

This command will ask for new ip address from the host machine ;i.e linux machine.